# Checking if point is within multipolygon using ST_Contains?

Tags: postgis, polygon

Why is this query always returning false?

```
SELECT ST_CONTAINS(the_geom,(select ST_GeomFromText('POINT(26.8715 80.7799)'))) FROM blockgeom
```

Can I not check if a point is within a multipolygon using ST_Contains?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can.  I think your coordinates are flipped.  That is usually the culprit.

For spatial databases the coordinates are generally x=longitude, y=latitude. So yours puts you somewhere out in the arctic ocean.  Try instead

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(80.7799 26.8715)')
```